# How to block sites after I close its last tab?

Tags: firefox, time, blocking, facebook

For concentration, I would like to block Facebook. However my work is also on there so I can't block it at any specific time. I just know that after I close its last tab, every work on it is done, Facebook is now disturbing. I want to block it for some hours after the last tab is closed. Is there any way to do this? I use Firefox.

Comment: Have you thought of using two browsers, eg **firefox** for work, **chrome** for FaceBook? I have found this quite successful for a number of related problems.

Comment: Yes I have. But the problem risen since the day work is discuss on Facebook. People say they can work while Facebook is opening, but I can't.

Comment: But the point is that you simply shut down Chrome (and therefore FaceBook) when you don't want distractions. There are even tools to start and stop programs at scheduled times.

Comment: Well, maybe I need something more powerful than myself :).